# "Today Events" standard component

Tags: lightning-experience, standard

The "Todays Events" component, when creating an event and selecting the "All day event" box, throws the event with the date of the previous day.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your Language and timezone setting. Steps to follow:-

1. Click on View profile in right top screen of Lightning Experience
2. In left-hand side pane, select Language and Time Zone
3. Check your correct Time Zone and save it

> Note:- Today's Event Standard Component only shows those events having
>   start date equals to today. It means Salesforce is recognizing the
>   previous day as your current date due to your time Zone setting.

Comment: Thank you!!! Sanket